# i am getting this error when I try to download pip install tweepy through my terminal

Tags: python, pip, installation, tweepy

```
copying tweepy/error.py -> build/lib/tweepy
copying tweepy/models.py -> build/lib/tweepy
copying tweepy/oauth.py -> build/lib/tweepy
copying tweepy/parsers.py -> build/lib/tweepy
copying tweepy/streaming.py -> build/lib/tweepy
copying tweepy/utils.py -> build/lib/tweepy
running install_lib
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/examples
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/examples': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/zq/k3pbc5v57gn07qqg7qxxnrmm0000gn/T/pip-build-R8mYNT/tweepy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zq/k3pbc5v57gn07qqg7qxxnrmm0000gn/T/pip-ZdPzhK-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zq/k3pbc5v57gn07qqg7qxxnrmm0000gn/T/pip-build-R8mYNT/tweepy/

Comment: run it as sudo?

Answer (score 0):

The Python installation is outside of your '/home/username/' directory. You need to use root privileges give you permission to access the directory.

```
$ sudo pip install tweety
```

- Using sudo as above will just apply the command(s) that follow it.